PagerView not stretching to fit its children
I am working on a React Native project with Expo, where I am using the react-native-pager-view component to create a slider. However, I am facing an issue where the parent container (subContainer) does not stretch to fit the size of its children.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
import PagerView from 'react-native-pager-view'
import { Image, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { CSS_BORDER, CSS_SPACING, GLOBAL_STYLES } from '@/ui/styles/Vars'

function ArtistPreviewSlidingCard() {
  const viewModel = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    profession: 'Photographer',
    imageUrl: 'https://picsum.photos/200',
    description:
      'John Doe is a photographer based in London. He is known for his work in fashion photography.',
    cta: 'View profile',
  }

  return (
    <View style={cstyles.card}>
      <View style={cstyles.textContainer}>
        <Text style={cstyles.name}>{viewModel.name.toUpperCase()}</Text>
        <Text style={cstyles.profession}>
          {viewModel.profession.toUpperCase()}
        </Text>
        <Text style={cstyles.description}>{viewModel.description}</Text>
        <Text style={cstyles.cta}>{viewModel.cta}</Text>
      </View>
      <Image source={{ uri: viewModel.imageUrl }} style={cstyles.image} />
    </View>
  )
}

const cstyles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    flex: 1,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: 16,
    height: 200,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'grey',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    borderRadius: CSS_BORDER.radius.roundedMedium,
  },
  textContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    width: '50%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  image: {
    width: '50%',
  },
  name: {
    ...GLOBAL_STYLES.highlightText,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  profession: {
    ...GLOBAL_STYLES.highlightText,
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  description: {
    marginTop: CSS_SPACING.small,
    fontSize: 14,
    color: 'black',
  },

  cta: {
    marginTop: CSS_SPACING.small,
    textDecorationLine: 'underline',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
})

export function ArtistPreviewSlider() {
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <PagerView initialPage={0} style={styles.subContainer}>
          <ArtistPreviewSlidingCard key={1} />
          <ArtistPreviewSlidingCard key={2} />
          <ArtistPreviewSlidingCard key={3} />
        </PagerView>
      </View>
      <ArtistPreviewSlidingCard />
    </>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  subContainer: {
    flex: 1,

    height: 100,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    borderRadius: CSS_BORDER.radius.roundedMedium,
    padding: 16,
    margin: 16,

    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'blue',
  },
})

[]
What I have tried:

Ensured that all components have flex: 1.
Removed flex: 1 from the subContainer style and set its height to auto.
Verified that the PagerView component has flex: 1.

If I set the height of the subcontainer to 100, I can see the card, but it's truncated until I give enough value.
Despite these changes, the subContainer still does not stretch to fit the exact size of its children. How can I make the subContainer stretch to fit its children properly? Any help would be appreciated.

You have a fixed height of 100. Take a look at it. In case you want to prevent height from being greater than, you should use maxHeight
  subContainer: {
    flex: 1,

    height: 100,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    borderRadius: CSS_BORDER.radius.roundedMedium,
    padding: 16,
    margin: 16,

    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'blue',
  },

